# A Question on Spherical Method for volume.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates

Im currently studying, calculus in spherical method.

I encounter some confusion with the function $f(ρ,θ,φ)$
in the following formula

$$ \displaystyle\iiint_{E} f(ρ,θ,φ) ρ^2\sinφdφdρdθ $$

Taking the volume of say bounded by Hemisphere $x^2 +y^2+(z-3)^2 = 9$ and a cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ some of the previous equations suggests $f(ρ,θ,φ)=1$. I'm a bit confuse if its because previous example takes a unitary distance between origin. Or is there some way i could find the value for $f(ρ,θ,φ)$ in the integrand?

Comment: Use `\rho`, `\varphi` and `\theta` instead.

Comment: Think of $f$ as a density at the point. For any volume calculation it will be 1, regardless of the geometry.  It comes into play when you are averaging some quantity (charge density, mass density ...) over the volume.

Comment: The issue here is finding the limits of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has nothing to do with spherical coordinates. If $A$ is a region of the space $\Bbb R^3$, then$$\operatorname{vol}(A)=\iiint_A1\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz.$$For instance, if $A=[a,b]\times[c,d]\times[e,f]$, then the volume of $A$ is $(b-a)(d-c)(f-e)$, and\begin{align}\iiint_A1\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz&=\int_a^b\int_c^d\int_e^f1\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_a^b\int_c^d(f-e)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\\&=\int_a^b(d-c)(f-e)\,\mathrm dx\\&=(b-a)(d-c)(f-e).\end{align}